# Autoscaling with only one droplet/instance on digital ocean

Tags: cloud, devops, digital-ocean, infrastructure

I just joined a startup as a dev but due to urgent needs doing some infrastructure work. The product is recently getting alot of hits and droplet(instance) that is hosting the product is close to cpu usuage. I personally want to autoscale but unfortunately we are not using any clusters and it is a single node/droplet.

Question:

Is there anyway to dynamically increase the droplet type so that the cpu utilization/memory/etc.. will increase without going down and bringing it back up? Some sort of autoscaling where the instance type will increase without going down and dynamic? Or if that is not possible what is next best thing?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old post. I recently found this service which might be helpful for your requirement - https://www.cloudflexer.io. This supports autoscaling DigitalOcean droplets.